# How to set custom(some calculate logic) color according to each pixel value(R,G,B) using KONVA

Tags: html5-canvas, konva

I am trying to convert the color of the pixel using KONVA image class.
The conversion method is as follows.

```
var avg = (R + G + B)/3;
if(avg > 200){
    pixelColorR = 255;
    pixelColorG = 255;
    pixelColorB = 255; 
}else {
    pixelColorR = 200;
    pixelColorG = 200;
    pixelColorB = 200;
}
```

So I'd like to get two colored grayscale images from RGB images like the following.

[image] ===>>>   [image]

But I can't figure out how to get the color of each pixel using Konva class.
And how to set custom colors.

Anyone can help me?
Thank you.